# issues with external memory devices in linux

Tags: ubuntu

Hello Running ubuntu mate when I try to drag and drop a file into an external media
such as an external drive or a usb stick I get the error message the destination directory is read only.Any Ideas?

Comment: Hey MRP, welcome to the site. This particular StackExchange site is for programming Q&A. This question is belongs on one of the other sites, namely https://askubuntu.com or unix.stackexchange.com . In any case, this question contents far too little detail to be answered beyond merely guesswork. " I get the error message the destination directory is read only" ... so make it not read-only then

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when we are working with memory cards with adapter that has read/write switch on them. You haven't said which type of storage you are using. With SSD and other device this problems mostly never occurs. It happens with Switched pendrive/cards which has read/write switch. Or you can check with `lsusb` for further detection.
Sometimes some application snippets require special permissions for drives too. It would be great if you add some logs.